# Apply conditional formatting based on dates listed in row

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to track support hours in a shared document and want to have the entire month turn red if the number of support hours allocated in the month exceed the client's allowance. The date of a task is entered on a row, along with a description of the task and the number of support hours used.

I am using the formula `=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(C2:C997,MONTH(A2:A997)=2)),0)` to find the total number of hours used in a given month (we'll do a new one each year), and I want all rows with tasks created during that month to turn red if this total exceeds 50.

|  | Date of task | Task information | Hours used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/24 | A task | 20 |
| 2 | 22/1/24 | Another task | 25 |
| 3 | 30/1/24 | A third task | 30 |
| 4 | 2/2/24 | A further task | 15 |
| 5 | 4/2/24 | Yet another task | 7 |
| 6 | 15/2/24 | Even more tasks | 18 |
| 7 | 29/2/24 | A leap task | 9 |

In the example, the tasks assigned in January total 75 hours, so rows 1, 2 and 3 should be highlighted in red. However, the tasks assigned in February only total 49, so those tasks in rows 4-7 should remain unaffected.

In the table I'm working on I've extracted the values of 75 and 49 to individual cells so I can conditionally format based on the value of those cells, but I'm struggling to find out how to define the range of the affected rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=50 <= SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C, EOMONTH($A$2:$A,)=EOMONTH($A2,))
```

1. Compares Month-Year, not simply month.
2. Assumes first cell in range to be conditionally formatted is `A2`

Comment: Thanks for that, works great - I was hoping to use the same formula to output the total hours used each month in a separate table but it only returns the first month of data, are you able to assist with that also or would this be a separate question? My table works but only for the month, not the year, which is why I ask

Comment: [Ask  a new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) that includes the formula that isn't working and I'll be happy to help if others don't get there first.